# ActiveRecord - Order by field throws StatementInvalid when calling last

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, sql-order-by

Creating a activerecord query and calling `last` which has an order using MYSQL's `order by field` throws a StatementInvalid exception.

For example:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > User.order('field(name, \'joe\')').last

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'DESC, "joe") DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1:
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY field(name DESC, "joe") DESC LIMIT 1
```

The issue is that activerecord is appending `DESC` to `name` inside of the `field` statement as well as outside.

Is there a better way to order by specific column values with activerecord, or a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
User.where("name LIKE ?", \'joe\').last!
```

If you're just wanting the last record, why bother with `order`?

Comment: I simplified my example to demonstrate the issue - in my case I am doing an order on locations, where the users suburb/city should be the first items returned. The reason I use `last` is I need to work out which item in the set is the previous record of another item.